# How to I disable the spooler service in with Windows PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

So I am trying to write a script that will disable the spooler service when it is running and enable the spooler service when it is not. Every time I run the script I keep on getting these two errors.

```
Stop-Service : Service 'Print Spooler (Spooler)' cannot be stopped due to the following 
error: Cannot open Spooler
service on computer '.'.
At C:\Users\pedri\Desktop\Turn On or Off Printer.ps1:8 char:2
+     Stop-Service -name "Spooler" -force
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: 
(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Stop-Service],
   ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
CouldNotStopService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopServiceCommand

Set-Service : Service 'Print Spooler (Spooler)' cannot be configured due to the 
following error: Access is denied
At C:\Users\pedri\Desktop\Turn On or Off Printer.ps1:9 char:2
+     Set-Service -name "Spooler" -startupType disabled
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: 
(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Set-Servi
   ce], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
CouldNotSetService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetServiceCommand
```

Code:

```
# Get the print spooler service
$service = Get-Service -Name "Spooler"

# Check the status of the print spooler service
if ($service.Status -eq "Running") 
{
    # Disable if Service is running
    Stop-Service -name "Spooler" -force
    Set-Service -name "Spooler" -startupType "Disabled"
    Get-Service -name "Spooler"
} 
else 
{
    # Enable if Service is not running
    Start-Service -name "Spooler"
    Set-Service -name "Spooler" -startupType "Enabled"
    Get-Service -name "Spooler"
}

pause
```

Comment: The error `PermissionDenied` is pretty obvious. You have to run the script as an administrator in an elevated PowerShell console.

Comment: I just ran it as admin and it was able to disable the printer but when I try to run it again to enable them back I get this error Service 'Print Spooler (Spooler)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service
Spooler on computer '.'

Comment: You cannot start a service when it's startup type is set to `disabled`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just replaced enabled with Manual.

```
# Check the status of the print spooler service
if ($service.Status -eq "Running") 
{
    $answer = Read-Host -Prompt "Will you like to disable the printers (y/n)"

    # Disable if Service is running and user says yes
    if($answer -eq "y")
    {
        Stop-Service -name "Spooler" -force
        Set-Service -name "Spooler" -startupType "Disabled"
    
    }

} 
else 
{
    $answer = Read-Host -Prompt "Will you like to enable the printers (y/n)"

    # Enable if Service is not running and user says yes
    if($answer -eq "y")
    {   
        Set-Service -name "Spooler" -status Running -startupType "Manual"
    }

}
cls
Get-Service -Name "Spooler"
echo " "
pause
```

Comment: Actually you just needed to swap the lines with `Set-Service` and `Start-Service` in your `else` block in your original code ... `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`